# Can I somehow use circular permutations to find out the number of positional isomers of a cyclic organic compound?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know this is a chemistry question, but I'm really curious to see if it could work. The question I encountered was the number of positional isomers of trimethyl-benzene.

To reduce it to a mathematical problem, one could think of it as the number of ways to arrange 3 similar objects in a circle with 6 slots. Also, clockwise and anti-clockwise arrangements are considered to be the same.

The answer to this particular problem is 3, but I wanted to see how I can reach this answer using circular permutations so that I can use it in similar problems directly.

Comment: At least for these question, the cases can be manually counted.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I wanted to do it using Combinatorics so that I can use it for other questions which would take much more time for a manual approach. @SarGe

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the "Polya enumeration theorem", which has been used in the past to count chemical compounds. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem